# Unity camera Camera animation follows different path in game

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, camera

I made a camera animation. When I trigger it in game, it goes higher than when I play it in the editor.

When I play the camera animation in the game editor. (ie the game isn't running)
[In editor](https://youtu.be/DC4Lc0qpyDQ)

When I play the camera animation in the game. It's triggered by a boolean, which is triggered by user input.
[In Game](https://youtu.be/csV_mqKpy8M)

What I've tried:

- Rebuilt the animation from scratch. The same bug happens.
- turned off the animation. No extra transforms are applied to the camera.
- Searched the code for additional transform.

This is a very odd bug, and to be honest, I'm not even sure where to begin fixing it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are animating the camera and probably the camera creates also coordinates in-game when you press play. This is why in the editor it's working, I think you should try some fixes:

- use a coroutine to move the camera via script(if the movement is easy)
- try to change canvas space to world space or overlay
- animate another object and make the camera follow it by making it parent or just use a script that

  `transform.position.camera = transform.position // the object`

It should work with some of these fixes